# Clear textarea after using formRemote in grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I've tried lots of stuffs already but It fails

$('#field')[0].reset();

$('#field').val('');

document.getElementById("field").value = "";

Everything doesn't work, is there something wrong with formRemote?

edit:

```
<g:formRemote class="ui reply form" name="entryForm"url="[controller: 'game', action: 'addReview']" update="review">
<input" id="reviewButton" type="submit" value="Add Review" />
```

Comment: What does the generated html look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't selecting the element correctly; in the statement:

```
$('#field').val('');
```

The `#field` refers to an element with an `id` of `field` (`id="field"`), which based on your posted gsp element would not be the case.  In a formRemote, when the id is omitted the name value is used as the id as well (at least according to documentation).  You could use:

```
$('#entryForm').val('');
```

Or assign an `id` to your formRemote, which I find more explicit and less grails magic.

Keep in mind, I'm fairly certain that formRemote is deprecated.

Comment: what do you mean deprecated? its obsolete? if so, what's better implementation for an ajax call?

Comment: It has been removed from the latest grails version; I think the general consensus is to use a 3rd party JavaScript framework - jQuery (which has a grails plugin) has `.ajax()`.